# Mount USB device on router - OpenWrt

Tags: linux, usb, mount, openwrt

I am new to OpenWrt and Linux/Unix shell. Prior to this, was using dd-wrt for 2 years. Recently switched to OpenWrt and got the basic setup done(wifi/internet working). I need to install transmission my router. But, USB device won't mount.

The Details of the router are as follows:

**Router Model:**
Asus RT-N13U B1

**Image flashed:**
chaos_calmer 15.05.1 (openwrt-15.05.1-ramips-rt305x-rt-n13u-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin)

**Usb Details:**
Crusier Blade 16GB usb 2.0
Formatted to ext4 using GParted bootable cd

**Drivers Installed:**

- kmod-usb-core(preinstalled)
- kmod-usb-dwc2(preinstalled)
- kmod-usb2
- kmod-usb-storage
- kmod-fs-ext4
- kmod-scsi-core(preinstalled)

Here are permissions for dev/sda, /dev/sda1 and /mnt (set 777 manually):

```
~#ls -l /dev
brwxrwxrwx    1 root     root        8,   0 Jan 17 21:56 sda
brwxrwxrwx    1 root     root        8,   1 Jan 17 21:56 sda1

~#ls -l ..
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root             0 Jan 16 21:28 mnt
```

Error while mounting:

```
~# mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /mnt failed: No such file or directory

echo $?
255
```

sda1 is present inside dev and /mnt directory exists. Still it shows an error.

I have tried installing/reinstalling and then mounting, but for the same result. Also when I disconnect the USB **sda** and **sda1** folders disappear and then reappear when USB is reconnected so I guess the device is being detected successfully.

What is it, that I am missing?

**Edit:**
Added edits as suggested in the comments.

**[dmesg output](http://pastebin.com/XSirDRRY)** *(The output is very big so linked it)*

**Edit 2:**
Switched to LEDE 17. Is more stable and have had zero issues in the past week.

Comment: Check again if `/mnt` does really exist.

Comment: Yes I even tried cd /mnt. The path changes to /mnt#

Comment: "[   11.550000] EXT4-fs (sda1): Cannot load crc32c driver."

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So does it mean the driver is missing or some other problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the critical part of the `dmesg` output is

> [    9.410000] mount_root: loading kmods from internal overlay
>
> [    9.940000] SCSI subsystem initialized
>
> [    9.960000] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
>
> [    9.980000] ehci-platform:EHCI generic platform driver [    9.990000] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: no of_node; not parsing pinctrl DT
>
> [    9.990000] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
>
> [   10.010000] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
>
> [   10.020000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
>
> [   10.100000] block: attempting to load /tmp/jffs_cfg/upper/etc/config/fstab
>
> [   10.120000] block: extroot: not configured
>
> [   10.130000] mount_root: switching to jffs2 overlay
>
> [   10.180000] procd: - early -
>
> [   11.020000] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Blade     1.27 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
>
> [   11.030000] sd 0:0:0:0: no of_node; not parsing pinctrl DT
>
> [   11.050000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 30529536 512-byte logical blocks: (15.6 GB/14.5 GiB)
>
> [   11.070000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
>
> [   11.070000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
>
> [   11.090000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
>
> [   11.120000]  sda: sda1
>
> [   11.130000] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
>
> [   11.550000]  **EXT4-fs (sda1): Cannot load crc32c driver**

oh no, this seems to be a bug

**Bug#819725: ext4 missing softdep on crc32c module**

https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2016/04/msg00013.html

the following workaround is **not applicable** because *initramfs* is a native file system at startup time (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs) and has no influence when the system is fully up (rootfs is mounted):

> Until this is fixed in the kernel package, you can work around it by
>   either:
>
> - Setting base-installer/initramfs-tools/driver-policy to "most"   instead of "dep"
> - Setting base-config/late_command to a script that adds crc32c to   /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

post the stack trace anyway, maybe there is another workaround

*this is overcomplicated stuff...*

here is maybe a solution https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=69175

> download kmod-lib-crc32c and kmod-crypto-crc32c

if this is not working maybe **the easiest solution is to format the USB stack as VFAT** and to wait for a new kernel...

---

this is not a *permissions error*. a permission error would return EPERM      -> *error code* 1  *Operation not permitted*

it would be interesting to know what exit code the `mount` returns. The **'exit behavior is very different in the several mount version'** i.e. `mount(2)` and `mount(8)`

for getting the *return value*, type in a shell the command

`mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

then

`echo $?`

the number is the returned exit code of the `mount`  (the *255* means *'exit status out of range'* in this case '-1', http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF)

a listing of the **mount(8)** exit codes is i.e. in http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/33167585/what-are-the-return-codes-values-of-linux-umount

http://www.becane.com/2014/09/02/understanding-exit-codes-and-how-to-use-them-in-a-bash-script

beside the *return value* mount(2) also sets an *error code* in `errno` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). printing `errno` in shell is a bit difficult it is easier to get a reference like **http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html** and search for the error string, in this case *No such file or directory*

the string *No such file or directory*  is system error  **ENOENT**

As a system error  **ENOENT** means *A pathname was empty or had a nonexistent component.* (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html)

try `sudo mount -t ext4  /dev/sda1 /mnt` because the stick is formatted in **ext4**

if this is not working `dmesg` output would be interesting

detach usb device, reattach usb device, type `dmesg` and see the output. in the output of `dmesg` you also see which drivers are loaded for the device

https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/usb.storage  says that you need several more drivers (`block-mount`, `kmod-scsi-core`,...) because a usb stick (USB Mass Storage class) is also a SCSI and a block device...

(linux system error codes are in http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html)

*print a stack trace `sudo strace -f mount -t ext4 -o default /dev/sda1 /mnt` and post it*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers learned a lot of things from this. Tried it with -t ext4 option as well, same result. The exit code returned was 255(which I guess is a bad news). Also tried block-mount even it wont mount the drive. scsi was preinstalled. Also went through the permissions topic, and set 777 for sda, sda1, mnt.

Comment: i edited the answer as i had a mistake because of return values and error codes. there is a big difference between the return values of mount(2) [-1 on failure, 0 on success, setting errno] and mount(8) [0 on success, ...]. print a stack trace with `sudo strace -f mount -t ext4 -o default /dev/sda1 /mnt` and post it

Comment: I actually got the USB device mounted. Installed a package named 'kmod-lib-crc32c' not sure what the purpose of this package is. Checked on openwrt's USB page only to find kmod-crypto-crc32c. There is a lot of confusion right now. Will update the details once I get time. Maybe, will post another question about crc32c package. Also upvoting for the helpful content in the answer.

Comment: kmod-lib-crc32c helps. This is very late selection of answer but I myself was confused about the things that I was doing back then and did not want to select wrong answer as right one.
This has to be one of the best replies to be found on internet.