# How to mount a memory filesystem onto a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, mount, pyfilesystem

I have a memory filesystem in Python, created in the following fashion:

```
import fs
mem_fs = fs.open_fs('mem://')
mem_fs.makedirs('/dir1')
with mem_fs.open('/dir1/file1', 'w') as file1:
    file1.write('test')
```

I want to mount this filesystem onto a directory in my OS filesystem (e.g., /home/user/mem_dir). I can create an object that would reference OS filesystem:

```
os_fs = fs.open_fs('/home/user/mem_dir')
```

But then I have no idea how to go about mounting *mem_fs* onto *os_fs*. I tried using *MountFS* class, but it only creates a virtual filesystem. I need to create a mount point in a way that other external applications (e.g., nautilus) would be able to see it and copy files to/from there. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just mount a `ramfs` volume provided by the kernel?

Comment: @Klaus do you mean using _mount_ command? I'd like to be able to do everything inside Python since this is just a tiny portion of my overall code.

Comment: You could look into something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29156997/6744133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same requirement, ans i've managed it this way

```
from fs.tempfs import TempFS
tmp = TempFS(identifier='_toto', temp_dir='tmp/ramdisk/')
```

it does mount create a directory, with an arbitrary name suffixed by _toto

tmp/ramdisk ❯❯❯ ls
tmpa1_4azgi_toto

which is totaly available as a standard filesystem in the host as in your python code

```
tmp/ramdisk/tmpa1_4azgi_toto ❯❯❯ mkdir test                                                                    
tmp/ramdisk/tmpa1_4azgi_toto ❯❯❯ ls                                                                            
test

 >>> tmp.listdir('/')
['test']
```

it look quite magic as it does not appear at all in the mounted host's filesystem

```
 ❯❯❯ df -ah | grep -E '(ramdisk|tmp)'                                              
tmpfs                       785M    1,7M  783M   1% /run
tmpfs                       3,9G    195M  3,7G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5,0M    4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                       3,9G       0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                       785M     36K  785M   1% /run/user/1000
```

and it does totally disepear when your code end, or when you call

```
>>> tmp.close()
```

tmp/ramdisk ❯❯❯ ls
tmp/ramdisk ❯❯❯

Cheers

Comment: This might not have the desired effect. While "tmpfs" in Linux means a ramdisk, i.e. a filesystem stored in memory, fs.tempfs seems to just be referring to an on-disk filesystem that is temporary. Edit: it turns out that whether /tmp is a ramdisk or a normal disk is dependent on the OS.

Comment: This is not in-memory.  If I close the python session the directory remains, and if i reboot the directory is still there.